# Dependence of coil inductance on shape

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, acoustics, geometry, inductance

I'm currently working on my physics project about guitar pickup coils and I can't find any articles about coils with different shapes then solenoids or toroids. Even finding consistent information about multiple layer coils is difficult. So I've been thinking if there is any way to calculate inductance of coil if only given parameters are length of the wire, diameter of the wire (with isolation) and two coil core dimensions. To be specific... i want to find most efficient way to wind a guitar pickup coil. Theoretically only the height of coil core is given because of guitar string spacing and anything else could be calculated.

Because i don't want to go too deep i settled on core thickness 5mm (based on blue prints of Stratocaster pickups). And I only have 0.15 mm diameter wire. How do i calculate the highest possible inductance of coil if its length is variable (I know that core permeability plays a huge role in final inductance, but lets assume that we have air core)? I tried to use some equations i found with c++ program and excel, but then i realized that the equation was for solenoids. I will place graph of my data below... input wire length was 1945m (that is the approximate length of coil i have at home), diameter 0.15mm and dimensions of Stratocaster core (on x axis is length of the core and on y axis is inductance in Henrys).

[image]

So you can see that maximum inductance i could achieve with my wire is 2.66 H, but when i assume that its inaccurate because of the dimensions of coil.